# Pyreverse complaining even after having Graphviz

Tags: python, graphviz, pyreverse

I want to be able to save the output in PNG and have installed Graphviz. Still it complains saying Graphviz is not installed:

> The output format 'output.png' is currently not available. Please
>   install 'Graphviz' to have other output formats than 'dot' or 'vcg'.

Comment: Figured it: Install Graphhviz for Mountain Lion from their website. I wonder why the python package didn't help. :/

Comment: mine didn't work even after doing so :(

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As mentioned in comments by @KanwarG the solution is to install Graphvis from as a proper package and not using the python package found using pip.

If using a mac then a solution is to used Homebrew. If you do not have Homebrew then follow [these instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Installation.html) to install it. Then it is easy to install Graphviz using the following command.

`brew install graphviz`

If you are using ubuntu Debian the following command is likely to work.

`apt-get install graphviz`

Hope this helps other people trying to find a solution.

Answer (score 11):

It worked out for me on windows by installing Graphviz from their [website](http://www.graphviz.org/download/). Then I added `C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin` to the "Path" environment variable (so the "dot" command is recognized by windows) :

[image]

Comment: For 64bit users, it would be C:\Program Files\Graphviz\bin. I added it to my account's environmental variable (as opposed to the System Env) and it worked. The annoying thing is, when I downloaded and installed the Graphviz package for Windows, it actually gives you an option to add itself to the System.Path but gently discourages yoi to do so because "t's not the default behaviour". Don't listen to what the package says!

Answer (score 8):

In Windows, the easiest way is to use the Windows equivalent of `Homebrew`, the package manager [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). Once you have that installed:

```
choco install graphviz
```

Comment: To set up choco on windows go to https://chocolatey.org/docs/installation. Then choco install graphviz.

Answer (score 1):

For those who still have the issue.
I'm using miniconda (anaconda) to create my virtual envs, and I'm using conda install Graphviz to do the installation.

Info about miniconda:
https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html

it installs a bunch of other packages as well (which is not the case if you use pip):

```
  cairo              pkgs/main/osx-64::cairo-1.14.12-he60d9cb_2
  expat              pkgs/main/osx-64::expat-2.2.10-hb1e8313_2
  fontconfig         pkgs/main/osx-64::fontconfig-2.12.6-h9850fc5_0
  freetype           pkgs/main/osx-64::freetype-2.8-h12048fb_1
  fribidi            pkgs/main/osx-64::fribidi-1.0.10-haf1e3a3_0
  gettext            pkgs/main/osx-64::gettext-0.19.8.1-hb0f4f8b_2
  glib               pkgs/main/osx-64::glib-2.66.1-h9bbe63b_0
  graphite2          pkgs/main/osx-64::graphite2-1.3.14-h38d11af_0
  graphviz           pkgs/main/osx-64::graphviz-2.40.1-h0a44026_0
  harfbuzz           pkgs/main/osx-64::harfbuzz-1.7.6-h171471c_1
  icu                pkgs/main/osx-64::icu-58.2-h0a44026_3
  jpeg               pkgs/main/osx-64::jpeg-9b-he5867d9_2
  libiconv           pkgs/main/osx-64::libiconv-1.16-h1de35cc_0
  libpng             pkgs/main/osx-64::libpng-1.6.37-ha441bb4_0
  libtiff            pkgs/main/osx-64::libtiff-4.1.0-hcb84e12_1
  libxml2            pkgs/main/osx-64::libxml2-2.9.10-h3b9e6c8_1
  lz4-c              pkgs/main/osx-64::lz4-c-1.9.2-h79c402e_3
  pango              pkgs/main/osx-64::pango-1.42.0-h0f8274a_0
  pcre               pkgs/main/osx-64::pcre-8.44-hb1e8313_0
  pixman             pkgs/main/osx-64::pixman-0.40.0-haf1e3a3_0
  zstd               pkgs/main/osx-64::zstd-1.4.5-h41d2c2f_0
```

After that pyreverse works fine.

Comment: Can confirm that it works. For reference, this is the command I used (the conda-forge is newer than the anaconda package)

`conda install -y -c conda-forge graphviz`