# How to get Class diagram from Python source code?

Tags: python, uml, class-diagram, pyreverse

I try to get a class diagram from Python source code in `Client` folder with `pyreverse` but it requires `__init__.py`

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\Desktop\project> pyreverse Client
parsing Client\__init__.py...
Failed to import module Client\__init__.py with error:
No module named Client\__init__.py.
```

I don't find any solution for this. Is there a way to get the diagram?

**Update:**
There are many files in `Client` folder:

```
Client.py
GUI.py
script.py
...
```

This is a part of the `Client.py` code:

```
import threading


class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socket = None
        self.listen_socket = None
        self.buff_dict = {}
        self.message_list_dict = {}
        self.lock = threading.Lock()
        self.target = None
        self.listen_flag = True
```

This is a part of the `GUI.py` code:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, title, font, client):
        self.title = title
        self.font = font
        self.client = client
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title(title)
        self.build_window()

    def build_window(self):
        pass


class LoginWindow(Window):
    def __init__(self, client, font):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__('Login', font, client)
        self.build_window()
```

Comment: Could you post the code for `Client` as well?

Comment: @Anwarvic I should post all the code or all the names of the file in `Client` folder?

Comment: So, `Client` is a folder not a class ... right?

Comment: @Anwarvic yes, `Client` is a folder contains many `.py` file.

Comment: @huy do you define class(es) in these files ?

Comment: @bruno I just update some example of my folder and some `.py` file inside the folder.

Comment: @huy, then you need to create `__init__.py` file inside this folder

Comment: @Anwarvic do you know what we code in `__init__.py`?

Comment: @huy, nothing... just an empty file

Comment: @Anwarvic it seems work, now I just need to convert `.dot` file to `.png` file.

Comment: @huy, Glad I could help

Comment: @huy just use the option `-o png`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks to @Anwarvic and @bruno, I came up with the solution for this.

Firstly, create empty `__init__.py` file inside `Client` folder:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\Desktop\project\Client> type NUL >  __init__.py
```

Then go to the parent folder of the `Client` folder where I want to get the class diagram:

```
(venv) C:\Users\User\Desktop\project> pyreverse Client -o png
```

But I got this error:

```
The output format 'png' is currently not available.
Please install 'Graphviz' to have other output formats than 'dot' or 'vcg'.
```

After some findings, I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839974/9500955). Then I can run the `pyreverse` without any error.

This is the class diagram I got using `pyreverse`:

[image]

Comment: Simply creating an empty via `touch __init__.py` and then running `pyreverse ./ -a1 -s1` and then `dot -Tpng ./output.png ./classes.dot` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't have an `__init__.py` in the folder that contains `Client.py`. You should be able to just create the file without putting anything in it, as its main purpose is to indicate that the folder is a package.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) about `__init__.py` for a more in-depth explanation about the file.

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient approach should be to have a Jupyter notebook extension that dynamically generates diagrams of the classes defined in a notebook somehow like the variable inspector - possibly with the option to specify an alternative root like `datetime` in the first answer to
[creating UML charts by Pylint/pyreverse within Jupyter labs / console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048687/creating-uml-charts-by-pylint-pyreverse-within-jupyter-labs-console).

Note: This would remove the restriction of `pyreverse` requiring the displayed classes to be part of a module.